# How to send ERC20 token from smart contract in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, swaps

I want to make a smart contract, where you can instantly swap your Ether to ERC20 token.

What I do have now:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.16 <0.7.0;

contract Swap {
    address owner;
    address constant tokenAddress = address(
        0x14eb2ab8e6d09000a98e3166b3cc994375071f69 //ERC20 token address
    );
    uint8[] validTokenAmounts = [2, 16, 32];
    uint256 constant tokenPrice = 75000000000000;

    function isTokenAmountValid(uint8 tokenAmount) private view returns (bool) {
        for (uint8 i; i < validTokenAmounts.length; i++) {
            if (tokenAmount == validTokenAmounts[i]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function swap(uint8 amount) public payable {
        require(
            msg.value >= amount * tokenPrice,
            "You sent incorrect amount of Ether"
        );

        ??transfer()?? // Here I don't know what how to send ERC20 tokens
    }
}
```

I have a second question too - how do I deploy contract with XXX amount of ERC20 tokens in smart contract? 
It's my first time with smart contracts, I hope you will find time to help me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Does your contract have a balance at token 0x14eb2ab8e6d09000a98e3166b3cc994375071f69?

Comment: @goodvibration, yes, I want to deploy contract with let's say 10 000 tokens (I don't know how to do it yet, but I'll try). Let's assume that I have those token in contract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This contract is what is called "ICO contracts" or Crowdsale contracts in Ethereum language.

To deploy tokens on a contract

1. Create a token by deploying a contract
2. Initial token supply is minted on some Ethereum account
3. You do a normal `transfer()` of these tokens to the token swap contract
4. Token swap contract itself can then `transfer()` right amount of tokens to the purchaser from its internal supply

```
require(newToken.transferFrom(address(this), whom, amount) == true, "Could not send tokens to the buyer");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
However I want to make a swap for already existing token.

Comment: Just transfers tokens you need to swap on the smart contract, you can skip steps 1 and 2.